# I am struggling to get a desired style/effect in my shopify(Ella theme)'s header when I target a class in my header.liquid file

Tags: html, css, shopify

Before I put forward my question I'd like to tell that I am a complete newbie in coding who has started to learn just a couple weeks ago.
So my question is:
I am trying to customize my theme in Shopify (more specifically Ella theme) and my target was to add a 'typewriter' affect to the text that I write in the header section. I went about as creating a complete new .css file in the assets section of the theme and then linked it to a new div class I created in header. liquid file. The code I am using for my "customertext.css" (this is the new file that I created) is:

```
.customertext {
  background: #182028;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 9vmin;
  color: #8bf;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 1rem 0 1rem 2rem;
}

@keyframes typing {
  0.0000%, 27.3488% { content: ""; }
  1.1395%, 26.2093% { content: "d"; }
  2.2791%, 25.0698% { content: "de"; }
  3.4186%, 23.9302% { content: "dev"; }
  4.5581%, 22.7907% { content: "deve"; }
  5.6977%, 21.6512% { content: "devel"; }
  6.8372%, 20.5116% { content: "develo"; }
  7.9767%, 19.3721% { content: "develop"; }
  9.1163%, 18.2326% { content: "develope"; }
  10.2558%, 17.0930% { content: "developer"; }

  30.7674%, 51.2791% { content: ""; }
  31.9070%, 50.1395% { content: "w"; }
  33.0465%, 49.0000% { content: "wr"; }
  34.1860%, 47.8605% { content: "wri"; }
  35.3256%, 46.7209% { content: "writ"; }
  36.4651%, 45.5814% { content: "write"; }
  37.6047%, 44.4419% { content: "writer"; }

  54.6977%, 75.2093% { content: ""; }
  55.8372%, 74.0698% { content: "r"; }
  56.9767%, 72.9302% { content: "re"; }
  58.1163%, 71.7907% { content: "rea"; }
  59.2558%, 70.6512% { content: "read"; }
  60.3953%, 69.5116% { content: "reade"; }
  61.5349%, 68.3721% { content: "reader"; }

  78.6279%, 96.8605% { content: ""; }
  79.7674%, 95.7209% { content: "h"; }
  80.9070%, 94.5814% { content: "hu"; }
  82.0465%, 93.4419% { content: "hum"; }
  83.1860%, 92.3023% { content: "huma"; }
  84.3256%, 91.1628% { content: "human"; }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0%, 100% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}

.typewriter {
  --caret: currentcolor;
}

.typewriter::before {
  content: "";
  animation: typing 13.5s infinite;
}

.typewriter::after {
  content: "";
  border-right: 1px solid var(--caret);
  animation: blink 0.5s linear infinite;
}

.typewriter.thick::after {
  border-right: 1ch solid var(--caret);
}

.typewriter.nocaret::after {
  border-right: 0;
}


@media (prefers-reduced-motion) {
  .typewriter::after {
    animation: none;
  }
  
  @keyframes sequencePopup {
    0%, 100% { content: "developer"; }
    25% { content: "writer"; }
    50% { content: "reader"; }
    75% { content: "human"; }
  }

  .typewriter::before {
    content: "developer";
    animation: sequencePopup 12s linear infinite;
  }
}

/**/
```

and the new code that I added in header.liquid file by creating a new div under an already existing div is:

```
<div class="customertext">
<h1 aria-label="Hi! I'm a developer">
  Hi! I'm a&nbsp;<span class="typewriter nocaret"></span>
</h1>
<div>
```

Moreover, I linked the new .css file by adding a tag in header.liquid which is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'customertext.css' | asset_url }}" media="all" onload="this.media='all'">
```

I was trying to achieve a typewriter affect on my text in header section but the only thing this does is to add a Text which does take fontsize and color from css file but shows no typwriter affect. I hope I explained it properly. Thank you for taking time to read this.